# Windows 10 won't take input from keyboard and mouse after reset?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

A friend asked me to look at his windows 10 computer when it stopped responding to keyboard and mouse input. He had just done a system reset in Windows (keeping his personal files). I tried a different keyboard and mouse with no luck, but they did work when accessing the BIOS, so I don't think it's a hardware thing. I figured that the reset had removed some USB device drivers, so I should use a PS/2 mouse and keyboard to reinstall them, however this computer does not have any PS/2 slots at all. He does not have a Windows 10 disc and there doesn't seem to be a recovery partition on the HDD, is there anything I can try to fix this?

Comment: Does plugging in another USB keyboard work? After or before a reboot?

Comment: We saw this recently around here being the USB 3.0 driver. Have you tried all USB ports? It would certainly help others to know the make and model of this computer. Have you tried safe mode? Have you left Windows on long enough and connected to the internet to possibly update drivers through Win updates?

Comment: Hi, different keyboards didn't work either, however his keyboard on a different computer worked fine. Tried all of the USB ports, I haven't tried leaving it on with the Internet as he was using a USB WiFi device so I'll try that now, thanks

Comment: Left it running today connected to the Internet but still nothing, it's a Dell Inspiron i3847-3078BK Desktop. Can't access safe mode as I can't give any input to Windows, either as keyboard shortcuts or selecting advanced options in auto startup repair.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Setup (Bios) go to Peripherals. Look for Legacy USB or USB Keyboard and Mouse. If this is disabled, Enable it. Save and Exit.

Comment: No option for legacy or keyboard and mouse but there was an option in advanced called USB controller which was already enabled.